# Hide cursor on NodeJS blessed

Tags: javascript, node.js, blessed

I want to hide the cursor in my blessed application.  I've tried using the following options:

```css
cursor: {
   color: "black",
   blink: false,
   artificial: true,
},
```

Inside the screen object, it didn't work. So, I've also tried using:

```
var cur = require('hide-cursor');
cur.hide();
```

which didn't work either.

Anyone got some ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the cursor object:

```
cursor: {
   color: "black",
   blink: false,
   artificial: true,
},
```

Or, try to put `cursor: 'false'` in your screen const. You don't need another module to remove the cursor.